# Problems regarding calculation of time complexity of a code

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I know about all the notations (Big O and small o,Big Omega,small omega ) bounds and everything. But I'm still a newbie at this and I read this piece of code :

```
   void Function(int n)
    {  int i=1, s=1;
       while(s<=n) 
        { 
          i++;
          s=s+i;
          printf("*");
        }
     }
```

The book says the running time is sqrt(n) or O(sqrt(n)). Can anyone help me out on how it is so?

Comment: Analyze how variable `s` changes. Can you think of closed-form expression for the value of `s`?

Answer (score 4):

In this algorithm, the key is to calculate how many times the while loop executes. Let's call it `x`. To find `x`, we must understand how `s` behaves in terms of `x`.

The variable `s` will be at most the sum of the first `x` terms of the sequence (1, 2, 3...). That is:

```
s = x*(x+1)/2
```

Now we must understand how `x` behaves in terms of `n`. That is, we need to find `x`, such as:

```
x*(x+1)/2 <= n

x*x+x <= 2n

x <= 1/2 * (sqrt(8n+1)-1)
```

So, given some `n`, the loop will iterate `O(1/2 * (sqrt(8n+1)-1))` = `O(sqrt(n))` times.

Answer (score 1):

first, you have convince yourself, the problem is bounded by `n` and the growth of `s`.

let see how fast `s` grows. every iteration, the current value of `i` will be added and `i` itself will add 1. that is, in the j-th iteration, `i`==j.

so, given any iteration, the current value of `s` is summing up from 1 to current `i`, which is roughly `i^2`, which will be compared to `n`.

therefore, the number of iterations, which essentially is `i`, will be bounded by `n`, that's why here is the relation of `sqrt(n)`.